# Distributed cache in hadoop

Tags: file, caching, hadoop, distributed

How do we update a file in distributed cache of hadoop.
Options:

1. Update the file in distributed cache and restart mapreduce job.
2. Replace file with the new file and change the pointer location to point to new location and restart map reduce job.
3. Append the new values in distributed cache and restart map reduce job.
4. Other options are.....

I googled but couldnt find the answer of my question so posting here.
Hope I would get answer.

Comment: what do you mean update? What do you need? To change the file, while a job is running? To change the file and then run a job? There is no cache, when no job is running... It is in HDFS and you add it in the cache when the job starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update DistributedCache when mapreduce job is running since otherwise it would be a critical race.

You have to restart the Job, and just submit another DistributedCache data - there is no DistributedCache persistent between jobs.

Comment: It means once a file is part of distributed cache we cannot update that?

Comment: For Instance - I have one property file which is placed in distributed cache,Now I want to replace property file with updated one in distributed cache. How Can I do that ? Just replace the old peoperty file with  updated property file or have place updated property file at new place and point that location in distributed cache.  Or any other options?

Comment: The file that you pass with -files option or addCacheFile is COPIED to distributed cache. You can overwrite the original when you like. The changes will apply  when you re-run the job.